# Too much classes with the same concept

Tags: c++, class, interface

I have 5 classes that are used as operators :

```
TurnOn , TurnOff , PushBox , Exit , Enter
```

And I have for each type , a string that holds a description of that type .

For instance :

```
class Places {

enum Type { Room1 ,Room2 ,Room3 ,Room4 };


// more stuff

};
TurnOn turnOn(Places::Room1);
string turnOnString = "TurnOn(Room1)" ;
```

I want to store the info in a map , so I have 5 maps for each operator :

```
map <string , TurnOn > opeatorTurnOn;
map <string , TurnOff > opeatorTurnOff ;
map <string , PushBox > opeatorTPushBox ;
map <string , Exit > opeatorExit ;
map <string , Enter > opeatorEnter ;
```

But now I have 5 maps with the same concept : a string with its operator .

How can I store the operators in one map so I won't have to hold 5 maps with the same concept ?

Comment: this seems like a flawed design, 5 operator classes that do NOT derive from a base class `operator` ? It would make more sense to derive all buttons from a base class and dynamically create new operators throughout the program when a predefined number. e.g. `operator * turnOn = new TurnOn;`

Comment: @Need4Sleep: (1) This should be an answer .  (2) I'll try to fix my design . Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how your operator classes are implemented (we have very little information), but I'd make a map of callables, something similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

struct op1
{
    void operator()(int i) { std::cout << "op1::operator() " << i << "\n"; }
};

struct op2
{
    void operator()(int i) { std::cout << "op2::operator() " << i << "\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(int)>> ops;
    ops["1"] = op1{};
    ops["2"] = op2{};
    ops["1"](42);
    ops["2"](42);
}
```

You could also always wrap the ops in lambdas if you don't use the `operator()` overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Make them all inherit from one base class, store pointer to base and use polymorphism.

Comment: I want to avoid polymorphism since each class has different methods .

Comment: You can have one polymorhpic entry point (say, `func()`) and once in that context you will know exactly what type the class is and whap available operations are present.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store heterogeneous data types in a map (or any other STL container for that matter).

The simplest fix is to subclass them all off of one base class and store the base class in your map.

EDIT: I didn't notice the desire to avoiding polymorphism (though, I really don't understand why). In any case, I think boost::any or boost::variant might help you. You can store them all as a boost::any.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html

Comment: see other answer, he specified he doesn't want a base class already.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::variant` is usually used for such things.

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems like a very valid answer given the current known design information.

Comment: and from me -1 also - because too much boost (great reason do downvote DeadMG isnt't it?).